# Switching companies - is this really a thing?

Tags: discussion

I've seen a few posts of late (often end up closed) where the OP asks if they should find another job (or quit). However, the term used is "switch companies".

This has got me wondering, is there some kind of hidden job-swap board somewhere that allows you to change employer like changing bank or energy supplier? I was always under the impression that applying for a new job is hard, especially one that's worth applying for. Or is that the issue, that the people "switching companies" are more like customers than employees?

Ultimately, can someone point me to this wonderful company switching comparison site so I can have a go myself? I quite fancy doing my current job but based from the shop at the end of my road and working directly for Richard Branson.

Comment: You are making too much of the words being used. "Switching companies" is the same thing as "finding a new job".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is clearly not a serious question.

Comment: As said RichardU, in IT, "switching company" is common sense, because it is often the only way to get proper raise and keep your salary up to what your skill worth on the market. Even our professors says that the 10 first year, IT people usually switch 3 to 5 times.

Comment: @Walfrat that's also why IT resumes tend to be much longer than standard resumes.  You tend to have a longer list of employers.

Answer (score 1):

It's a term, not a service.

For many of us, especially in IT, you're not likely to spend too much time at one company.  In IT, it's rare to find someone who's been there more than five years, for example.

That said, there is, in fact a methodology.  You are always looking for a better company in certain fields as that is the only way you will get a pay bump.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the term switching companies is exactly what is happening.

I have been at places where the government contract is awarded to another company. The new company makes offers to the employees of the old company. Your choice is find another contract/project with the old company or stay in the same seat, but switch companies. What you do depends on how much you like the work, the location, the benefits packages, and the prospect of long term employment. There are only perfunctory interviews, and the paperwork can be so easy that the employee has zero unpaid days.

Otherwise when they say switching companies, they mean finding a new job.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, switching companies is a "thing", as is using an internet search engine.